Values of quadratic function and its discriminant
The question might be trivial, but I confused in one step which I tried to mention.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ where $a\neq 0$.
Suppose that $f(x)\ge 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
I do not understand, why discriminant of $f$ (i.e. $b^2-4ac$) should be negative?

It might be trivial, but I got confused with values of function and discriminant; discriminant tells only possible roots of $f$; how the values of $f$ pose condition on discriminant of it?

Do you remember how to complete the square?

It's not true. Consider $f(x)=x^2$.

I came to the doubt for Proof 2 in this article https://rgmia.org/papers/v12e/Cauchy-Schwarzinequality.pdf.

Although it says that $\Delta<0$, it used $\Delta\color{red}{\leq }0$ in the proof, which is correct. Maybe it's a typo.

As the comment says, this is not true in general. For example, consider $f(x)=(x+1)^2\geq 0$, where $a=1,b=2,c=1$. We have $\Delta=b^2-4ac=0$, which is non-negative. However, the following is true:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ where $a\neq 0$.
Suppose that $f(x)\color{red}{>} 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\Delta<0$.

The reason is that if $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then $f(x)=0$ has no roots, which implies that $\Delta<0$.
[Recall: $\Delta<0$: no roots, $\Delta=0$: one root, $\Delta>0$: two roots]
Here is another way to explain, if $\Delta\geq 0$, then $x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$ satisfy $f(x)=0$, which is a contradiction.
